# How to vertically center label between two other labels in auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I came across this past question: [vertically center UILabel between two other lables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770875/vertically-center-uilabel-between-two-other-lables) and unfortunately, this method is not producing successful results for myself.  I know how to center my label horizontally and I just unaware of how to position my label equally between two labels.  How would you recommend I go about this?

Comment: What does “not producing successful results” mean? What results do you get?

Comment: Drag out a UIView, pin the top of the view to the bottom of the top label, pin the bottom of the view to the top of the bottom label, add the label to the view and align the center of the label with the vertical center of the view.

Comment: The desired height between the two labels was not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using stack views? If you put all the buttons in a vertical stack, you can fine tune the spacing from the attributes inspector.

Here's a link to a tutorial on YouTube. 
http://youtu.be/O0llR7sfrkc

Comment: Appreciated.  To add some information, there are a total of five buttons.  One is attached to the top layout guide, one to the bottom, and one right in the middle.  It's just a matter of positioning the other two with no real anchors between the top/bottom and middle.

Comment: A hacky way to do it is put uiviews between them. Set the UIViews to have equal heights. As long as the buttons have fixed heights, it'll work.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial!  I skipped around and I was able to accomplish exactly what I was going for!  Thank you, again!

Comment: Glad to hear it! When you have time, try and watch the whole thing. Stack views can make life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put all 3 labels inside of a stackview.

In storyboard select all three labels, and down beside the pin and align buttons will be the Stack button.  Click that and then your labels will be placed in a stackview.  You can edit how they are displayed and the spacing in the attributes inspector.